# Truncate multiple files at *nix command line

Tags: bash, truncate, xargs

I know how to empty a file's contents without deleting it:

```
echo "" > catalina.out
```

but I want to do it to multiple files in a single command (or command pipeline). What is the most elegant way to do that?

**What I've tried so far**

Usually I'd experiment with something involving `find` and `xargs` but if redirection is part of your xargs command I am not sure if the binding precedence would be interpreted the way I intend. I tried this and it didn't work:

```
find $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/ -type f | xargs --delimiter "\n" -n 1 -I% echo "" > %I;
```

I'd prefer to use find + xargs rather than find -exec or tee + process substitution if possible. (For those that care, my belief is that `-exec` bypasses the extensibility of pipelines. Maybe not so much in this example but the more corner-cases I can figure out how to use pipes with, the more advanced my understanding of pipelines will be - I think Doug McIlroy's school of thought is underutilized. Also, commands inside strings ruin your editor's syntax highlighting capabilities)

---

**Answer** (credits to redneb below)

I find the `find -print0 | xargs -0` idiom cumbersome, I prefer to use xargs --delimiter. So here's the way I have settled on which is a variation on the accepted answer:

```
find $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/ -type f | xargs --delimiter "\n" truncate --size=0
```

I am also using the long option `--size` of truncate since self-documenting code is more human-readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `truncate` command:

```
find $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/ -type f -exec truncate -s0 {} +
```

`truncate -s0` truncates a files to 0 bytes. Truncate has the advantage that it can be called on multiple files.

If you prefer to use `xargs`, you can do it like that:

```
find $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 truncate -s0
```

But I think this is less elegant.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize `truncate` was a command. Thank you :) (I'll mark correct as soon as the site let's me!)

Comment: This is a good example of why programs that supports stdin input are more true to Unix style and leverage their power (as truncate does).

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, which doesn't have the `truncate` command by default, you can use clever redirection and `tee` as an alternative.

```
find $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/ -type f -exec tee {} + < /dev/null
```